# Flask: Как перезапустить Web App программно?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, azure

У меня есть 4 паука Scrapy, которых я запускаю через Flask на Azure. Как перезапустить приложение по нажатию кнопки на моем сайте? Как использовать [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/restart) в функции Flask?

restart:

```html
<a href="/restart" class="btn btn-danger">Restart</a>
```

flask:

```
@app.route('/restart')
def restart():
    # REST API
```

Comment: REST API - тупо через библиотеку requests. Никакой сверх-магии.

Answer (score 0):

Установить scrapyd и отправить API запрос.
Отменить джобу(https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#cancel-json) -> запустить(https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule-json)